# windows logon and send fn + space + space

Tags: autohotkey

On windows logon I would like to send function + Space + Space to enable ThinkPad backlit keyboard.  following is my code but it's not working.

```
$#l::

Send {asc 0255}{Space 2} 

Return
```

Comment: `+` means `Shift`. Also, Fn key is sent differently AFAIK. Something like `Send {SC163 down}{Space 2}{SC163 up}` - the exact code is shown in the AHK tray icon dialog.

Comment: `fn` doesn't necessarily correspond to any key. I've seen many laptops that only receive a key event once you press fn in combination with another key.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention WHAT about this does not work.
The script is activated by a hotkey, so this is not a "Logon script" per se - ie it does not do something when you log on, it does something when you hit a key.

Does the script work if you are already logged on and hit the key?

If so, if you place the script in your startup folder, then hit the key after login, does it work?

If so, if you remove the line `$#l::` and place it in your startup folder, does it work automatically on login?